# How can I display data to a textbox from data grid view in Archestra?

Tags: wonderware

I want to display the data in textbox from the datagrid view by selecting different rows in the Archestra software.Is there a syntax so that i can display the data?

currently I am using the syntax

```
textbox1.text =selectedrows.item(0)
```

I need a syntax so that I can display the selected row in a text box.

I need to do this in wonderware Archestra software.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to retrieve the entire row into a string with one command. You would need to read the currently selected row and then each column in turn. You could then concatenate it into a string.

Small example:

```
DIM x;
x = #Grid.GetRowNumber();
Grid\column1 = #Grid.GetRowColumnValue( x, 0);
Grid\column2 = #Grid.GetRowColumnValue( x, 1);
....
Grid\selectedRow = Grid\column1 + Grid\column2 + ...
```